# Task body doesn't execute

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Now this one is driving me crazy. Using .NET Fx 4.0, I have the following delay mechanism:

```
private static Task Delay(double milliseconds)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += (obj, args) => { tcs.TrySetResult(true); };
    timer.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I call it in the following code:

```
// delay the execution of SendKey to let the dialog show up
var sendKeyTask = Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
{
    // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
    SendKeys.Send(filePath);
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());


MyButton.InvokeMember("click");
sendKeyTask.Wait(3000); //will time out after 3 seconds. 

....
```

The problem is that `SendKeys.Send(filePath);` line is never executed. What am I missing?

Comment: Synchronous waiting and asynchronous continuation on the main context in one place is almost always a bad idea. I'd bet that there's a deadlock between the continuation of `sendKeyTask` and `.Wait(3000)`, especially since the continuation is scheduled to run on 'current' synchronization context. The `Delay` itself seems to work, I tried it in LINQPad.

Answer (score 0):

What @PatrykĆwiek said.
Remove the `Wait(3000)`, and if you want something to happen after `sendKeyTask` is completed - do it in a continuation (or do it in the `sendKeyTask`, as it is running on the current thread.. whatever is more appropriate).

Comment: Thanks Shlomi. I can't figure out what I need to write after the `InvokeMember()` line. I need to wait for sendKeyTask to complete before leaving the current function. Is there something better than `Wait()` for that purpose?

Comment: First, if you work async - then, work async. The best solution would be to return the `sendKeyTask`, so the method's caller could attach continuation to it. The other solution (which I think might complicate things even more), is not to wait and execute on the same thread.. but `SendKey` needs to run on the UI thread... so, we back in square one... So, the other solution is 'don't do async': Wait on the `Delay` task (or just call `Thread.Join`), and then just call `SendKey.Send` synchronously

Comment: I'll try to simplify: either you work async, then, you return the `sendKeyTask` (and the caller can attach continuations to it). or you work "sync", which means you blocking the current thread, then calling `SendKey.Send`, then you return, and you don't need to wait until it's done (as it's alread done.. as all regular (not async) calls).